# Internal Server Error when submitting html / PHP form

Tags: php, html, forms, internal-server-error

I am coding a basic webpage and one of the requirements is an html form that submits input via a php file.

I have coded the following in the html file:

```
<form method="post" action="formsubmit.php" name="Contact Form" id="contactform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset>
            <legend align="center">
                Your Details
            </legend>

            <p>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <label for="fname">First Name: </label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" required/>

                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <label for="sname">Surname: </label>
                <input type="text" id="sname" required/>

                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <label for="email">Email Address: </label>
                <input type="email" id="email" required/>

                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <label for="phone">Phone Number: </label>
                <input type="tel" id="phone" required/>
                <br />
                <br />

            </p>


        </fieldset>
                <fieldset>

            <legend align="center">
                Third Parties
            </legend>
            <p>
                <label for="sharedetails">Tick this box if you would like to recieve ticket and event information from our carefully selected third parties.</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sharedetails" value="sharedetailsno" id="sharedetails" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                <input type="reset" value="Clear" />

            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

and then created the following php file:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Process Feedback</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
</head>
<body>

<?php
$fname = $_POST["firstname"];
$sname = $_POST["surname"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];

$sharedetails = $_POST["sharedetails"];

print "test test $fname $sname $email $phone test test"; 
?>



</body> 
</html>
```

obviously the php file is still in the test phases and i only want it to return the submitted data before I format it properly with correct data output etc

but it keeps returning 'Internal Server Error' whenever I submit the form. I have searched the internet for answers and have found similar posts but none that have helped my problem

I am running apache server on my local system. ¿could the problem be some misconfiguration?

If I can get the form data to submit properly to the php file then i can format the rest of the html page / output page.

Comment: Your HTTP server's error logs should contain a message indicating why this script failed to run.

Comment: just noticed i missed a " in the php file on charset, corrected

Comment: Have you set apache up to work with php?  Do you have a working hello world php page?

Comment: those post variable don't exist.  they need to be the same as the names of the inputs

Comment: John B- your right, i used the label instead of the input ID, i have corrected this now, thanks.

Comment: cdhowie- i am looking at the logs but there are no errors relating to my php files, which make me think it is an apache problem.

Toby Allen- I configured apache when i first installed it but have not used it since, can you recommend configuration instruction to make sure apache is working with php?

Comment: Which logs are you looking in? `apache/error` ? Is it the right log for that virtual host? What happens if you browse to a php page containing nothing but `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have form `name` attributes on the first page set equal to your `$_POST` array elements on the second page.

This should be your code the the first page:

```
<form method="post" action="formsubmit.php" name="Contact Form" id="contactform" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <fieldset> 
            <legend align="center"> 
                Your Details 
            </legend> 

            <p> 
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 

                <label for="fname">First Name: </label> 
                <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" required/> 

                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 

                <label for="sname">Surname: </label> 
                <input type="text" name="sname" id="sname" required/> 

                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 

                <label for="email">Email Address: </label> 
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required/> 

                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 

                <label for="phone">Phone Number: </label> 
                <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" required/> 
                <br /> 
                <br /> 

            </p> 


        </fieldset> 
                <fieldset> 

            <legend align="center"> 
                Third Parties 
            </legend> 
            <p> 
                <label for="sharedetails">Tick this box if you would like to recieve ticket and event information from our carefully selected third parties.</label> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="sharedetails" value="sharedetailsno" id="sharedetails" /> 
            </p> 
            <p> 
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
                <input type="reset" value="Clear" /> 

            </p> 
        </fieldset> 
    </form>
```

This should be the code for formsubmit.php:

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Process Feedback</title>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">  
</head> 
<body> 

<?php 
$fname = $_POST["fname"]; 
$sname = $_POST["sname"]; 
$email = $_POST["email"]; 
$phone = $_POST["phone"]; 

$sharedetails = $_POST["sharedetails"]; 

print "test test $fname $sname $email $phone test test";  
?> 



</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Too much clutter just use the basics to start with.

Get rid of

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

You are not using the ids correctly

```
$_POST["fname"];
```

instead of:
    $_POST["firstname"];

You need to join your output and echo them

```
echo "test test ".$fname.$sname.$email.$phone."test test";
```

Comment: Though this is good advice and OP needs to clean up his code, this will not resolve the Server Error question OP is asking.

Comment: thanks, i had used the label instead of the ID tags, this is correct now.

ill try the echo output